# How to display a block view if a page view has 1 single result?

Tags: views

The scenario is like this:

I have a page on which I have the header, the block in question, a lot of other stuff, and then the page view (its a table) that actually provides the route, the footer.

If the page view has one single row, I need to display the block view with some contextuals. Everything works (the results are ok, the contextuals are ok) except for the part where I need to check if the view page has one single result so I can display the block.

I am not sure how to go about that. I've tried some twig in my block view but I am not that knowledgeable with it.
I am looking for advice.

If it helps, the page and the block belong to the same view.
I am using Drupal 8.8.6.